# How to return double values in SOAP service in java?

Tags: java, soap

I'm implementing a simple SOAP service in java. I have a simple business Layer class that has 2 functions: get all product names, and another one to get product price.

I have a Service layer class that initialize the products data and sent to the business layer and call methods of business layer.

If I test the classes as regular java application all functions work  and the getPrice return the product's price (10.00, 15.00, or 18.00). However, once I deployed it as a web service and try to test it either by SOAP client or via Glassfish tester GUI, the function of get price always return 0.0 ( it does not return the product's price).

Here is BL code:

```
package BLayer;
import java.util.*;

public class ProdBL{
   HashMap<String, Double> prods ;

   public ProdBL(HashMap<String, Double> prods ){
      this.prods = prods;
   }

   public String getNames(){
      String s ="";
      for(Map.Entry<String, Double> e: prods.entrySet() ){
         s+= e.getKey();
      }
      return s;
   }

   public double getPrice(String name){
      double s =0.0;
      for(Map.Entry<String, Double> e: prods.entrySet() ){
         if(e.getKey() == name) {
            s = e.getValue();
         }
      }
      return s;
   }


}
```

Here is Service layer code:

```
package SLayer;
import java.util.*;
import BLayer.*;
import javax.jws.*;

@WebService(serviceName="MyProdService")
public class ProdService{
   HashMap<String, Double> prods ;
   ProdBL bl;

   @WebMethod(operationName="intiliazeProducts")
   public String init(){
   this.prods = new HashMap<String, Double>();
     this.prods.put("A",10.00);
     this.prods.put("V",15.00);
      this.prods.put("D",18.00);
      this.bl = new ProdBL(prods);
      return "Products Initilzed";
   }
    @WebMethod(operationName="getProdNames")
   public String getNames(){
      String s ="";
      s = bl.getNames();
      return s;
   }
   @WebMethod(operationName="getProdPrice")
   public double getProdPrice(String name){
      double price =0.0;
//       ProdBL blp = new ProdBL(prods);
      price= bl.getPrice(name);
      return price;
   }

}
```

Client class:

```
import proxies.*;

public class Client{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      MyProdService s = new MyProdService();
      ProdService port = s.getProdServicePort();
      try{
         port.intiliazeProducts();
         System.out.println(port.getProdNames());
         port.intiliazeProducts();
       System.out.println(port.getProdPrice("A"));


      }catch(Exception e){

         e.getMessage();
      }
   }
}
```

Why does getProdPrice always return 0.0, while getNames() work fine? This happens even when I test it in SOAP UI or Glassfish generated tester interface.

Comment: You are comparing strings with `==`

Comment: Oops That's right. I was looking for mistakes in the web service  because it run and works in regular java application. Thank you ^_^.

Comment: The problem is in the title. You should ***never*** use floating-point for money. Use a decimal radix.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to rewrite your code like this:


package SLayer;
import java.util.*;
import BLayer.*;
import javax.jws.*;

@WebService(serviceName="MyProdService")
public class ProdService{
   private static HashMap<String, Double> prods ;
   private static ProdBL bl;

   static {
       prods = new HashMap<String, Double>();
       prods.put("A",10.00);
       prods.put("V",15.00);
       prods.put("D",18.00);
       bl = new ProdBL(prods);
   }

    @WebMethod(operationName="getProdNames")
   public String getNames(){
      String s ="";
      s = bl.getNames();
      return s;
   }
   @WebMethod(operationName="getProdPrice")
   public double getProdPrice(String name){
      double price =0.0;
      price= bl.getPrice(name);
      return price;
   }

}
```